# Base change for prime-to-$p$ fundamental group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-covers

Let $k$ be an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$. Let $X$ be a connected smooth quasi-projective $k$-scheme. If $K$ is an algebraically closed field containing $k$, is the prime-to-$p$ etale fundamental group of $X$ isomorphic to that of its base change to  $K$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the canonical map $X_K\rightarrow X$ induces an isomorphism on $\pi_1^{(p)}$. You can find [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.09690) a detailed proof of a slightly more general statement.

Comment: for future use, in case the link gets broken, this is :  
*Aaron Landesman,
Invariance of the fundamental group under
base change between algebraically closed fields*.

Comment: A friend contacted me asking for a permanent home for this write up, so it is now posted at https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.09690

Also see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/257722/is-the-map-on-etale-fundamental-groups-of-a-quasi-projective-variety-upon-base?rq=1