# Base change for fundamental group prime to p in mixed characteristic?

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, schemes, etale-cohomology, etale-covers

I found the answer to this question while typing it up, but since I've already written it, it is probably worthwhile to post-and-answer in case someone finds it useful.

Let $S=\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_K$, $K$ a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, $k$ its residue field, $f:X\to S$ a smooth projective flat irreducible scheme with $f_*\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_S$. Do we have an isomorphism $\pi_1^p(X_{\overline k},\overline{s})\cong\pi_1^p(X_{\overline{K}},\overline{\eta})$ induced by an "algebraic closure" $\mathcal{O}_K\to\mathcal{O}_{\overline K}$, i.e. an equivalence between prime-to-$p$ connected étale covering spaces of the two varieties?

If this holds, the prime-to-$p$ assumption is necessary, an elliptic curve with Frobenius lift is a straightforward enough counterexample otherwise. My impression is Abyankhar studied more interesting pathologies of $\pi_1$ of characteristic-$p$ curves that don't appear in the characteristic zero case as well.

In the Abelian case this should follow from smoothproper base change: $H_1\left(X_{\overline k};\hat{\mathbb{Z}}^p\right)=H_1\left(X_{\overline{K}};\hat{\mathbb{Z}}^p\right)$, where $H_1\left(X_{\overline k};\hat{\mathbb{Z}}^p\right):=H^{-1}\left(R\operatorname{Hom}\left(R\Gamma\left(\hat{\mathbb{Z}}^p\right),\hat{\mathbb{Z}}^p\right)\right)$ (is isomorphic to $H^{2d-1}\left(X_{\overline k};\hat{\mathbb{Z}}^p(d)\right)$) and similarly for $\overline{K}$.

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328380/base-change-for-prime-to-p-fundamental-group) and [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/257722/is-the-map-on-%C3%A9tale-fundamental-groups-of-a-quasi-projective-variety-upon-base) are something like an equicharacteristic version of this, but the mixed-characteristic version seems harder with the lack of Lefschetz principle.

Comment: [Rubber-duck ~debugging~ proving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) at its best!  (I tried a bunch of ways of formatting strikethrough, but none of them worked, so imagine, please.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes: this kind of question is discussed at length in SGA I, Exposé X. In particular, the specialization homomorphism $\pi_1(X_{\overline K},\overline{\eta})\to\pi_1(X_{\overline k},\overline s)$ is surjective (Corollaire 2.4.) That it induces an isomorphism on prime-to-$p$ fundamental groups is Corollaire 3.9.