# Fundamental group of a product in characteristic 0

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fundamental-group, etale-covers

It is proven in SGA1 that if $k$ is an algebraically closed field, if $X$ is a proper $k$-scheme and if $Y$ is a locally noetherian $k$-scheme (say, $X$ and $Y$ are non-empty and connected) then $\pi_1(X\times_k Y)=\pi_1(X)\times \pi_1(Y)$. This implies that if $L$ is any algebraically closed extension of $k$ then $\pi_1(X\times_k L)=\pi_1(X)$.
All of these results are known to fail without the properness assumption, but all counter-examples are in positive characteristic, and I am almost sure that this assumption can be removed in char. $0$.

**Question**: is it written somewhere? I did not find any proof of it in SGA, nor in Stacks Project.

For the commutation with the product over $\mathbb C$ one can use the corresponding result in topology and the comparison theorem between étale and topological fundamental groups, but reducing the case of an arbitrary algebraically closed field of char. 0 to that of $\mathbb C$ would first require a proof of the invariance of the $\pi_1$ under algebraically closed extension.

Comment: The invariance of fundamental groups under extensions of alg. closed fields in char. 0 is discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/257722/is-the-map-on-etale-fundamental-groups-of-a-quasi-projective-variety-upon-base/257762#257762). Since then Aaron Landesman has also written up a proof of the invariance here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.09690.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much! The quasi-projectivity assumption in the ArXiv paper you refer to looks strange. I think it is probably not necessary?

Comment: @AntoineDucros it seems that by van Kampen it suffices to treat the affine case?